# BigQuery NOT LIKE using Query Result

Tags: filter, google-bigquery

T1:

```
Users
name   | meta_value
"Alex" | "hair_color=blonde"
.....
```

T2:

```
 Banned_hair_colors
    ban_date     | color
    "2020-01-01" | "blonde"
    "2020-01-01" | "brown"
    "2020-01-01" | "green"
```

Hi,
I need to filter the users table based on the hair color and not show the ones that are in the Banned_hair_colors table.

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE  
meta_value like "%blonde%"
and meta_value NOT IN (
                SELECT color  
                FROM `Banned_hair_colors`
            )
```

^ The above query works when the value "blonde"

But I need a "Not Like" solution because what I have in the Users table as value is not identical to what I have in the Banned_hair_colors.

I've tried different ways, but because I have the values from the other table as a result from a inner query, not sure how to make it work.

What I've tried:

```
    SELECT * FROM `Users`
where 
meta_value like "%blonde%"
and not exists (
  SELECT 1 from `Banned_hair_colors`
  where `Users`.meta_value like concat('%',`Banned_hair_colors`.color,'%')
)
```

I get the error: LEFT ANTISEMI JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE meta_value LIKE "%blonde%"
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT u.* FROM `Users` u
JOIN `Banned_hair_colors` b
ON meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%', color, '%')
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your comment. When I've tried this example, I get:  EXCEPT DISTINCT has type that does not support set operation comparisons: STRUCT, These examples are dummy data from a more complicated data set. It seems that the table has a Struct dataset, any ideas in how to approach this?

Comment: update your question with representative examples of input data and expected result - see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)